# How to make a dotted grid using css?

Tags: css

I need to make dotted background like on the example
[image]

i've tried to use background-image and it works but i don't know how to make gaps between dots only for even or odd columns

```
 background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 1px 1px, black 1px, transparent 0);
 background-size: 40px 40px;
```

Comment: Can you use an actual image, since this appears to be a fixed-size grid design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the background size to 2x the spacing between your dots.

Have 3 dots for every repetition of the background:

- top-left, like you already have
- top-center
- center-left

The result should look something like this:

```css
#testcase {
  width: 370px;
  height: 360px;
}

.background {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at  2px  2px, black 2px, transparent 0),
                    radial-gradient(circle at 42px  2px, black 2px, transparent 0),
                    radial-gradient(circle at  2px 42px, black 2px, transparent 0);
  background-size: 80px 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="testcase" class="background">
</div>
```

Note: made the dots a bit bigger to better show the result

[edit]

This can also be asymmetric, "skipping" 1 dot horizontally and "skipping" 2 dots vertically.

Divide the width into 2 equal parts, like the first example. I chose a repeating width of 80px, so have a top row of 2 dots with spacing of 40px between them.

1. First dot at 2px, 2px
2. Second dot at 42px, 2px

Divide the height into 3 equal parts. I chose a repeating height of 90px, so have a left column of 3 dots with spacing of 30px between them.

1. First dot at 2px, 2px (this is the same as the first dot for the horizontal row, no need to duplicate)
2. Second dot at 2px, 32px
3. Third dot at 2px, 62px

The result should look something like this:

```css
#testcase {
  width: 370px;
  height: 360px;
}

.background {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at  2px  2px, black 2px, transparent 0),
                    radial-gradient(circle at 42px  2px, black 2px, transparent 0),
                    radial-gradient(circle at  2px 32px, black 2px, transparent 0),
                    radial-gradient(circle at  2px 62px, black 2px, transparent 0);
  background-size: 80px 90px;
}
```

```html
<div id="testcase" class="background">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you also show me how to make gap in two dots?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include how to have such a larger gap in dots

Answer (score 1):

Add another gradient to hide some dots:

```css
html {
 background-image: 
  conic-gradient(#0000 75%,#fff 0),
  radial-gradient(black 2px, transparent 0);
 background-size: 
  80px 80px,
  40px 40px;
}
```

Using CSS variables for better control:

```css
html {
 --s: 40px; /* control the overal size */
 --r: 6px;  /* control the radius of the circles */
 --b: #f2f2f2; /* the background color */

 background: 
  conic-gradient(#0000 75%,var(--b) 0)
   0 0/calc(2*var(--s)) calc(2*var(--s)),
  radial-gradient(black var(--r),var(--b) calc(var(--r) + 1px))
   0 0/var(--s) var(--s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you also show me how to make gap in two dots?